# Is the API for exercise machines (like NordicTrack iFit) open? Can I write an app to control my bluetooth-enabled machine?

Tags: android, bluetooth, embedded

I've written standalone apps that construct workouts that I can build to vary time, resistance, etc., but they don't communicate with a dedicated exercise machine. I recently bought a NordicTrack elliptical machine which uses their iFit framework (using their iFit Bluetooth app) to control the machine's resistance and incline. Is this an open Bluetooth-accessible API that I can access to have my app connect to the machine and manipulate the resistance and incline myself? Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

It's not open because the companies (ProForm, NordicTrack) want to earn extra money besides the one time purchase price through constantly flowing subscription money via the iFit service. They need to somehow make it an exclusive option to use iFit, otherwise they'd lose another cash cow, I'd even say maybe the constant subscription flow is more important than the MSRP.

On fitness forums (like slowtwitch forum https://forum.slowtwitch.com/forum/Slowtwitch_Forums_C1/Triathlon_Forum_F1/Treadmill_iFit_%22hack%22_/_tweak_P6851409/) people were figuring out how to get into admin mode and access the Android tablet as it is. Lately Nordictrack moved and tries to block the users from accessing privileged mode condescendingly in the name of safety: https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/329275-owners-resort-to-hacking-smart-treadmills-after-nordictrack-locks-them-out. This is similar what Peloton pulled: https://www.makeuseof.com/peloton-treadmills-lose-free-just-run/

However when communication happens with apps there always be a possibility to reverse engineer protocols, although that's tedious and sometimes result in fragile code, and condescending companies could always push updates which intentionally interfere with hack solutions.

According to forums the https://github.com/belden/iFitController web protocol based solution (mentioned by @papahouss, I found another repo which exists) only works with 2017 and earlier devices. The later models switched to Bluetooth (it sounds like you have such machine) so the HTTP project won't work for you most probably.

There are a few projects trying to integrate iFit devices with Zwift, and some other extra projects. This one particularly looks very promising, but I haven't got to study it in details yet: https://github.com/dawsontoth/zwifit/blob/master/src/ble/ifit/_request.js

Comment: Related https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22774/hacking-old-gym-equipment/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at this project : https://github.com/jamesdotcuff/iFitController

You can communicate with the machine via websock. It works for treadmill but not too sure about elliptical machine.

Good luck

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Every time that you answer a question on SO, please try to comment it. Ones the link deads, there will be no answer.

Comment: @papahouss I will take a look at that project. Thanks.

Comment: Project link mo longer after 2022 wanting to connect to my ifit treadmil nordick